# Is this Database UPDATE command with calculation correct?

Tags: java, sql

I want to set the `ArtikelAnzahl` (the number of article) in the database to the term, which I will get from my Java GUI.

So the SQL command string should look like:

```
    "update warenliste set Anzahl=Anzahl+"anzahl"where Artikel_ID="+arikel_ID;
```

where:

- `warenliste` is the table and `Anzahl` is a comlum which should get updated.
- the number of article in the DB should be added to the number which we will get from the GUI.

Is this command right? I just learned SQL yesterday and unfortunately am not yet good at it.

```
public void setArtikelAnzahl(int anzahl, int arikel_ID) {           
        try {
            String query = "update warenliste set Anzahl=Anzahl+"anzahl"where Artikel_ID="+arikel_ID;
            rs= st.executeQuery(query);             
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Well, do you get any errors when you try to execute it?

Comment: Looks like it's full of syntax errors to me, and like your query is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: Your code does not compile, change to: `String query = "update warenliste set Anzahl=Anzahl"+ anzahl + " where Artikel_ID="+arikel_ID;`, but better google and learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Don't concatenate input into SQL strings. Use a PreparedStatement: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/

Answer (score 0):

### The SQL part

The SQL part of the query seems fine if `artikel_id` and `anzahl` are both numeric (and that it's `anzahl` and not `artikeanzahl`).

Let's instantiate the statement for an imaginary article 1 and a quantity of 27:

```
update warenliste set Anzahl=Anzahl+27 where Artikel_ID=1;
```

If you test this [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adA2vWePEd5KgXHzLdGa3F/0) with the following schema, it will work out fine:

```
create table warenliste (artikel_ID numeric, 
                         bezeichnung varchar(100),
                         anzahl numeric);

insert into warenliste values (1,"Schraubenzieher", 1050);
insert into warenliste values (2,"Hammer", 10347);
```

### The Java part

But there are a couple of problems in the Java part. First, you need to correct the statement to make the Java code compile.  You also need to add missing spaces in the result string:

```
   String query = "update warenliste set Anzahl=Anzahl+"+anzahl+" where Artikel_ID="+arikel_ID;
                                                        ^      ^ ^
```

Since you're not too familiar with SQL yet, I'd suggest to [display](https://ideone.com/dbWRug) the `query` string before you execute it. Just to verify that it matches your expectations.

Now if `ariktel_id` is a string, and not a numeric,  you may have to add the missing quotes around in the query string around the variable.

It's not required, but I'd recommend that when you build the query string, you use uppercases in the SQL statements.  This will facilitate reading the java code, especially when you'll have SQL strings mixed with java variables like here.

Comment: But how can i use my int variable "anzahl" in this query? 
I get the java variable "anzahl" from my GUI and want to add the current number ("Anzahl" in the quote) with my java variable "anzahl"

Comment: @Funkeyfreak look in the java part of the answer

Comment: I think I understand the answer but still i dont know what to do with my command...

i need to add a variable but cant use "+". You say that i should add some missing quotes around the variable, but i really dont know whtat u mean.

"String query = "update warenliste set Anzahl=Anzahl" 'anzahl' "where Artikel_ID="+arikel_ID;"   is obviously false too. 
I really dont know what i should add or delete... 

the example with adding something into a database without java variable is easy, but with a java variable is hard (for me).

Comment: @Funkeyfreak Please have a look at the link embedded behind “display” in my answer. I uses the corrected statement in an online compiler to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: @Funkeyfreak no problem ! I’m glad if it could help

Comment: @Funkeyfreak `String query = "insert into warenliste (Artikel_ID, Artikelname, Anzahl, Hochfrequent) values ("+artikel_ID+",' "+artikelname+"', "+anzahl+", "+hochfrequent+")";`  - Depending on DB, use single quote in java string constant as in this example,  or use a double quote with escape char, i.e. `...+artikel_ID+",\" "+artikelname+"\","+anzahl+...` - Caution typo in artikel_ID.